# Coons patches in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex

The current method of drawing Coons patches in `pgfplots` requires four cubic Bézier curves along with point meta values for each corner point.  This closely follows the format used in the PDF specification.  I am currently creating a large shaded area and have noticed that each surface is created separately, each time using edge flag `f = 0`.  I feel this method fails to exploit the reuse of previous Bézier curves provided by the PDF specification.  Looking at the `pgfplots` surface shading library, I noticed there is a `\pgfplotslibrarysurf@edgeflag` option under `\pgfplotslibrarysurf@type=6`.  While I realise that Coons patches are intended primarily for internal use, I was hoping there was a way to define the edge flag when specifying the coordinates of a Coons patch.

Alternatively, is there a better approach for including Coons patches in a pdfLaTeX document?  The interface provided by `pgfplots` already allows me to obtain the correct visible result, but for several large plots, produces rather large files.  Using the edge flags would reduce the number of coordinates for each surface from 24 to 16 (at 3 bytes each) and the colour data from 4 to 2 (at 2 bytes each), reducing the size of each patch from 81 to 53.  I'm not sure how difficult this would be to implement, but as it already seems so close and there is the potential to significantly reduce the complexity of the plots, it seemed a worthy question.

Answer (score 4):

As author of `pgfplots`, I have a natural interest in your question and I honor your efforts to look up the details of the PDF spec.

The short answer would be: a coordinate-based compression for Coons patches (which affects `patch type=bilinear|biquadratic|bicubic` and most other `patch types` of the `patchplots` lib) would be a feature requests for `pgfplots`.

Let me stress your own word that this is purely about the size of the pdf, not about the outcome (which is unaffected).

Other answers might be given regarding "better approaches for including Coons patches in pdflatex".

---

I believe this answers the question for the scope of TeX.sx . However, I have a personal interest in this topic, so I would like to point out some details. If you'd like to discuss the details, you can contact me by mail; I fear a lengthy discussion would be off-topic here.

I can tell you that respecting the edge flag in `pgfplots` would involve quite some programming effort - and the cheapest part would be the backend driver (which would silently omit coordinates). The problem is that the plot handler would need to (a) know the sequence of patches or (b) need to automatically compare adjacent patches. The first appears to be difficult and/or clumsy in genernal and even impossible in the case of `z buffer=sort`, the second needs programming effort and careful testing.

So, on the one hand, you would need to write support - don't know how complicated it would be, but anyway. Are you sure that the savings justify the effort? After all, you still have pdf compression in place. How much would you save anyway, based on your estimate (i.e. how many patches do you have in your application)? 300kb? More? Less? Much more?

I always thought that the size of these documents does not matter *that* much as long as it is "reasonable". And `pgfplots` already *is* very compact (compared to the pdfs generated by matlab's interpolated shadings, for example).

---

**edit**: I made a brief computation: a matrix of 24*24 Coons patches would save 20KB in uncompressed pdf size. Assuming a compression rate of 2:1, you would save 10KB.

And 24*24 is probably reasonable: if you had finer mesh widths, you would probably be unable to distinguish the Coons patch visually from a trivial triangle shading (which has considerably less space).

Here is the computation: Let us suppose that you have a grid of 25 times 25 grid points. This would delimit 24*24 = 576 cells. Let us assume that each cell is shaded using a Coons patch. Currently, pgfplots would occupy 576*81 = 46656 bytes for this shading. With your suggested optimization, it would be 576*53 = 30528. Savings: ~20KB (uncompressed). Or did I screw up the computation (wouldn't be the first time...)?

Comment: While each picture contains few patches, I'm planning to produce a large number of plots so was looking for a more efficient solution (partly due to curiosity too). I agree with your computation - the saving is quite small. I was also considering how much of an impact there would be on rendering by the PDF viewer for large images. I see that the necessary changes probably aren't worth the effort, but may try to achieve what I want externally and use `\addplot graphics`. Could anyone suggest a good place to start to learn about manually producing a minimal PDF with a single Coons patch object?

Comment: I have written shaders for triangle patches in libpoppler/xpdf. From what I know, that library could also make use of a good shader for Coons patches. Perhaps that is something for you ;-)  . Note that `libpoppler` decodes the stuff into main memory, i.e. the compression should have a neglible effect.

Comment: If you want to produce minimal pdf, you could use `pdflatex`, a `pgfplots` picture, and `\pdfcompresslevel=0` as first statement in the `.tex` file. Afterwards, you could try to learn from it, perhaps even patch it.

Comment: The pdf I have produced with coons patches using pgfplots seems to render properly in xpdf but causes a segmentation fault.  In libpoppler, it renders without crashing, but shows a white grid.

Comment: Could you send me your offending `.tex` file along with the broken `.pdf` file by email? My address can be seen on the pgfplots manual title page. How do you check that it renders correctly with `libpoppler`?